# socket.emit emits two times

Tags: node.js, socket.io

i am having problem with the socket.emit using socket.io. i have an object of connected clients, when i emit a message to a specific client using socket.emit, it emits two times!
any solution.

here is the code.

```
var clients ={};
    io.sockets.on('connection',function(socket){
    socket.on('verifyId',function(data){
         clients[data.user_id]=[];
             clients[data.user_id].push(socket);
        });

     socket.on('saveConverse',function(data){
    user1=clients[data.to];
    if(clients[data.to])
    user1[0].emit('newMessage',{msg:'hi, here is a new message!'}); 
            //here it is emitted two times.
     });
 });
```

Comment: What is `saveConverse` listening for?

Comment: saveConverse is an event triggered by client, to save a conversation. and then it is emitted to a particular client, whom it is sent for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing

```
user1[0].emit('newMessage',{msg:'hi, here is a new message!'});
```

with this:

```
io.sockets.socket(socketid).emit('newMessage',{msg:'hi, here is a new message!'});
```

Because this is the proper way to emit to a specific client. Aslo,
you can save socket IDs instead of the whole socket object in `clients` array by `socket.id`.